# pdfbox class cast exception

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, apache-tika

I want to read the text from the following pdf file. I am using `pdfbox` version 1.8.8. I am getting the following error.

```
2014-12-18 15:02:59 WARN  XrefTrailerResolver:203 - Did not found XRef object at specified startxref position 4268142
2014-12-18 15:03:00 ERROR PDPageNode:202 - No Kids found in getAllKids(). Probably a malformed pdf.
2014-12-18 15:03:00 ERROR PDPageNode:202 - No Kids found in getAllKids(). Probably a malformed pdf.
2014-12-18 15:03:00 ERROR PDPageNode:202 - No Kids found in getAllKids(). Probably a malformed pdf.
2014-12-18 15:03:00 ERROR PDPageNode:202 - No Kids found in getAllKids(). Probably a malformed pdf.
2014-12-18 15:03:00 ERROR PDPageNode:202 - No Kids found in getAllKids(). Probably a malformed pdf.
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.COSStreamArray.<init>(COSStreamArray.java:68)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.createFromCOS(PDStream.java:185)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.getContents(PDPage.java:639)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:380)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:344)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:275)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:288)
    at com.algotree.pdf.test.PdfBoxTest.pdftoText(PdfBoxTest.java:53)
    at com.algotree.pdf.test.PdfBoxTest.main(PdfBoxTest.java:71)
```

Yes,i have seen many posts about this error. Still i couldnt find the solution to read this file.
Thanks

[file.pdf](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/467057/F2014_2014F.Traders.TradersMagazine.201408.201206.pdf)

This is my code:

```
static String pdftoText(String fileName) throws IOException {
        PDFParser parser;
        String parsedText = null;;
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        COSDocument cosDoc = null;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            System.err.println("File " + fileName + " does not exist.");
            return null;
        }
        try {

            parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to open PDF Parser. " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        try {
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdfStripper.setSuppressDuplicateOverlappingText(false);
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            int endPage=pdDoc.getPageCount();
            if(endPage>300)
                endPage=300;
            pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
            pdfStripper.setEndPage(endPage);
            parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(cosDoc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (cosDoc != null)
                    cosDoc.close();
                if (pdDoc != null)
                    pdDoc.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return parsedText;
    }
```

Comment: I received a 12MB PDF from your link, is that correct?

Comment: @mkl yes.thats the one

Comment: I asked because that file actually is a concatenation of three PDF files, i.e. *as a whole it is an **invalid** PDF*.

Comment: the link requires to run an installer?!

Comment: btw it would be useful to post a few more lines of the exception stack trace, please edit your question.

Comment: @mkl yes. i think so.. so cant we read the content from this pdf file?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i hv updated the question. plz take a look

Comment: @TilmanHausherr *the link requires to run an installer* - no, I wouldn't have d/l'ed the file then. But it still was a PITA, I needed to use a throw-away e-mail address.

Comment: yup.. i dont know how to attach a file in stackoverflow question.

Comment: from the full trace I'd agree with mkl that the file is invalid. Only quick solution I can think of is to catch Throwable so that your application doesn't crash as a whole. Btw your code seems to be based on some outdated sample code that is all over the web. Documents are to be loaded with PDDocument.load(file) or PDDocument.loadNonSeq(file, null)

Comment: @DinoopNair *so cant we read the content from this pdf file* - You shouldn't expect getting proper results from a broken PDF. I'd propose splitting up the file (the individual file lengths are 3798944, 3980563, and 4437803) into its three components which at first glance seem proper PDFs, and try to extract text from them. *i dont know how to attach a file in stackoverflow question* - SO only allows to attach images, thus external file sharing services are necessary. But one should use services which are not a PITA, e.g. public shares on google drive or dropbox.

Comment: @mkl thanks..i ll follow ur instructions :)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr    pdDoc=PDDocument.loadNonSeq(file, null);
This one works.. thanks :)

Comment: Looks like there might be an Apache PDFBox bug. Did you retry it with the latest version of PDFBox?

Comment: @Gagravarr i think 1.8.8 is the latest vesrsion. im using it

Comment: You'll need to report it as a bug to Apache PDFBox, and upload a sample file to the JIRA which shows the problem

Answer (score 2):

This one works

```
static String pdftoText(String fileName) throws IOException {
    String parsedText = null;;
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    PDDocument pdDoc = null;
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (!file.isFile()) {
        System.err.println("File " + fileName + " does not exist.");
        return null;
    }
    try {
        pdDoc=PDDocument.loadNonSeq(file, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to open PDF Parser. " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    try {
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        int endPage=pdDoc.getPageCount();
        if(endPage>300)
            endPage=300;
        pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(endPage);
        parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        System.out.println(parsedText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (pdDoc != null)
                pdDoc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return parsedText;
}
```